# Getting actual text in freetextbox control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using [FreeTextBox control](http://www.freetextbox.com/)

in asp.net.When I am getting its Text in my code I am getting the Html code with all the formatting.

If I want to get the actual text (i.e. only text without html tags),then how I should get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Your_FreeTextBox.HtmlStrippedText
```

> Gets the Text stripped of Html tags

http://www.freetextbox.com/docs/ftb3/html/P_FreeTextBoxControls_FreeTextBox_HtmlStrippedText.htm